# Conditionally set bibliography title

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, optional-arguments, class-options, options

I am writing a class and would like to offer the option of changing the bibliography title as a class option. If no title was given I would like to just use the default one. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this working. Neither using an if-clause in the options to `\printbibliography` nor using `\setkeys` with either of the keys I found in `biblatex.sty` (`blx@bib1`, `blx@bib2`, `blx@biblist1`, `blx@biblist2`, `blx@bhd`) produced the expected resut. The first option results in an error, the second one just doesn't do anything.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newif\ifbibtitle

\newcommand\SetBibTitle[1]{\def\bibtitle{#1}\bibtitletrue}

\bibtitletrue

\SetBibTitle{My Books}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{Chomsky1957}.

% This doesn't fail but also doesn't change the title
\ifbibtitle
    \setkeys{blx@bib1}{title=bib1}
    \setkeys{blx@biblist1}{title=biblist1}
    \setkeys{blx@bib2}{title=bib2}
    \setkeys{blx@biblist2}{title=biblist2}
    \setkeys{blx@bhd}{title=bhd}
\fi

\printbibliography

% This fails
% \printbibliography[\ifbibtitle title=\bibtitle\fi]{}    

% T.. as does this.
% \printbibliography[{\ifbibtitle title=\bibtitle\fi}]{}

\end{document}
```

I know that I could do:

```
\ifbibtitle
    \printbibliography[title=\bibtitle]
\fi
```

But I would like to solve this problem in such a way that I can also conditionally change other settings for other commands without having to go through all permutations of those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_makkototo_printbibliography_opts_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \makkototo_printbibliography:n #1
  {
    % Call the original \printbibliography command
    \__makkototo_printbibliography_orig [#1]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \makkototo_printbibliography:n { V }

% Name of the command from the MWE
\NewDocumentCommand \SetBibTitle { m }
  {
    % Append the title option to \g_makkototo_printbibliography_opts_tl
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_makkototo_printbibliography_opts_tl { title={#1}, }
  }

% Call \printbibliography with the contents of
% \g_makkototo_printbibliography_opts_tl at the beginning of the optional
% argument. Pass on #1 unmodified after this contents.
\NewDocumentCommand \myprintbibliography { O{} }
  {
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_tl \g_makkototo_printbibliography_opts_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \makkototo_printbibliography:V \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\AtBeginDocument
  {
    % Save the original \printbibliography and make \printbibliography
    % \let-equal to \myprintbibliography from now on
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \__makkototo_printbibliography_orig \printbibliography
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \printbibliography \myprintbibliography
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\SetBibTitle{My Books}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{Chomsky1957}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

It's easy to extend to other options: simply copy and adapt `\SetBibTitle`.